# Cassandra Query Token function gives No viable alternative at input error

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax

I am trying to run below query against Cassandra table using datastax python cassandra connector. I am getting "no viable alternative at input 'TOKEN (...ECT TOKEN...)" error. Is there anything wrong in the query? Please help me as i am new to Cassandra.

```
statement = SimpleStatement("SELECT TOKEN(doc_id), doc_id FROM <ks>.<tablename> WHERE TOKEN(doc_id)>-8939575974182321168 AND TOKEN(doc_id)<8655779911509866528", fetch_size=30)
rows = session.execute(statement)
```

Comment: The query in itself looks correct. Is doc_id your partition key and is that the only part of it? It would be difficult to tell the reason for error unless I know what the partition key of your table is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It worked after removing TOKEN(doc_id) from columns section but WHERE condition remains same. SELECT doc_id FROM <ks>.<tablename> WHERE TOKEN(doc_id)>-8939575974182321168 AND TOKEN(doc_id)<8655779911509866528"

Comment: can you provide the table structure by executing `DESCRIBE TABLE <ks>.<tablename>` @sureshbabu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply. It worked after removing TOKEN(doc_id) from columns section but WHERE condition remains same. SELECT doc_id FROM . WHERE TOKEN(doc_id)>-8939575974182321168 AND TOKEN(doc_id)<8655779911509866528" –